# Converging Leaflet usage from JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm converting usage of Leaflet in project from `.js` files to `.ts`, and when I use **line**

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([0, 0], 7);
```

in `.ts` then I **receive**:

> Cannot find name 'L'

Comment: How have you imported Leaflet ?

Comment: @Seblor By   <script src=node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js></script>

Comment: Are you sure you imported Leaflet *before* your code ? (Also I assume you forgot the add the quotes in your comment)